# Robot framework not allowing me to print over multiple lines

Tags: python, robotframework

Robot framework doesn't allow me to print over multiple lines. I've tried the "..." method and no luck.

```
Log To Console  Hello my name is Adam
...    \n What is your name?
```

The output is just "Hello my name is Adam". I've tried to change the tabbing and multiple different things but nothing seems to work. I was originally using pycharm thinking it was a EOL issue and moved to notepad++ and started running it through the cmd and was faced with the same issue. I am running robotframework version 4.0. This worked with robotframework 3.0. Before raising it as a bug, wanted to know if i was doing something wrong?

I can get around this issue by using the code below but it doesn't fix the original issue

```
${Var}= Catenate    Hello my name is Adam
...     \nwhat is your name
Log To Console  ${Var}
```

Comment: I'd consider this  as a parser issue/bug ..  File a bug in github ?

Comment: yeah thinking about doing that, just wanted to make sure i wasn't doing something wrong

Comment: I have no clue which way it _should_ work, so not able to answer your question here either, but you can also have the strings printed with separate ``Log to Console`` commands instead of the ``(...)`` ellipsis. They will appear as if a single string and you can even remove the automatic new line by giving ``no_newline=true`` to the previous keyword.

Comment: I think this is how `Log to console` is designed to work. The entire log message must fit in one argument. That means it's impossible to continue the message onto another line. You could pretty easily write your own keyword which accepts multiple arguments and then logs them to the console.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for the reply. Log To console is a simple one but i've notcied that the Fail keyword has a similar issue. I want to let the user know why my tests failed and want to utilise the message arg. I have to shorten my message because of this bug

Comment: It's a fundamental aspect of robot framework that you can't split a single cell scroll multiple lines. I'm not sure I would call it a bug, it's just  how it was designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Create several strings on multiple lines, then merge them:

```
${greeting}=   Catenate  \nHello my name is Adam
${question}=   Catenate  \nWhat is your name?
${dialog}=   Catenate  ${greeting}  ${question}
Log To Console   ${dialog}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can separate each line with a \n.

```
Log To Console    Hello What is your name?\nMy name is Adam
```

Output:

Hello What is your name?

My name is Adam